# Unable to bind a tag to Google Kubernetes Engine cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to bind a tag for GKE cluster but not unable because:

```
google_tags_tag_binding.gke-tag-value-binding: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error creating TagBinding: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
│     "fieldViolations": [
│       {
│         "description": "Must be a valid One Platform resource name of a tag-compatible global resource. Did you forget to specify the correct location?",
│         "field": "binding.resource"
│       },
│       {
│         "description": "Resource type not supported in location global",
│         "field": "binding.resource"
│       }
│     ]
│   }
│ ]
│ 
│   with google_tags_tag_binding.gke-tag-value-binding,
│   on main.tf line 162, in resource "google_tags_tag_binding" "gke-tag-value-binding":
│  162: resource "google_tags_tag_binding" "gke-tag-value-binding" {
│ 
╵
```

Terraform plan:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_tags_tag_binding.gke-tag-value-binding will be created
  + resource "google_tags_tag_binding" "gke-tag-value-binding" {
      + id        = (known after apply)
      + name      = (known after apply)
      + parent    = "//container.googleapis.com/projects/xxx/locations/asia-southeast2-a/clusters/gke-cluster"
      + tag_value = "tagValues/xxx"
    }
```

My code related to tag:

```
resource "google_tags_tag_key" "gke-tag" {
    parent      = "projects/${var.gcp-proj}"
    short_name  = "gke-cluster"
    description = ""
}

resource "google_tags_tag_value" "gke-tag-value" {
    parent = google_tags_tag_key.gke-tag.id
    short_name = "gke-cluster-true"
    description = "It's True"
}

resource "google_tags_tag_binding" "gke-tag-value-binding" {
    provider = google.oprek
    parent = "//container.googleapis.com/${google_container_cluster.gke-cluster.id}"
    tag_value = google_tags_tag_value.gke-tag-value.id
}
```

What's wrong with my Terraform configuration? I think the code defined is right and following the documenatation.

Related documentation:

[Google Cloud Doc: Manage GKE resources using Tags](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/tags)

[Terraform Registry Doc: Google Provider - resource.google_tags_tag_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/tags_tag_binding)

Answer (score 0):

**CASE CLOSED**

I change the code to:

```
resource "google_tags_location_tag_binding" "gke-tag-value-binding" {
provider = google.oprek
parent = "//container.googleapis.com/${google_container_cluster.gke-cluster.id}"
tag_value = google_tags_tag_value.gke-tag-value.id
location = var.gcp-zone
```

}

and works well